# Conditionally stop jQuery animation when in second function alternation

Tags: jquery, animation, click, hover

I'm running 2 types of animations that coincide with each other.

1. Is a on click, which reveals a sidebar.
2. Is a hover, which reveals a tweet as well as the sidebar (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/15/))

My problem is, when the sidebar is open, and my hover tweet animation runs, when I hover off the tweet area, it closes my sidebar which I do not want it to do.

If tried numerous if and else statement is my script but am failing to get them to work as per I need them too. Can anyone help?

My script is below, but see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/15/) to see [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/15/) - http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/15/

```
// The variables

var $sideBar = $("#sidebar"),
    $openClose = $("#menu"),
    $tweet  = $("#latest-tweet");


// The twitter script load via JSON

$("#tweet").tweet({
    count: 1,
    username: ["motocomdigital"],
    loading_text: "searching twitter...",
    intro_text: null,
    outro_text: null
}).bind("loaded", function(){

    // Binded function and variable because I need the tweet's dynamic height

    // Tweet height, once tweet has loaded

    var tweetHeight = $("#tweet").innerHeight();

    // Tweet (red block) .hover action

    $tweet.hover(function() {

        // Opens tweet (red block) horizonally and vertically
        $tweet.stop().animate({ top: "-" + tweetHeight + "px", right: "0" }, 300);

        // Opens sidebar horizonally
        $sideBar.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);

    }, function() {

        // Closes tweet (red block) horizonally and vertically
        $tweet.stop().animate({ top: "0", right: "-250px" }, 300);

        // Closes sidebar horizonally
        $sideBar.stop().animate({ right: "-250px" }, 300);

    });

});


// The side bar and tweet animation sequence when "open menu" is clicked.

$openClose.on('click', function () {
    if ($openClose.html() == 'Close Menu') { // run if button says "Close Menu"

        // Closes sidebar horizonally
        $sideBar.stop().animate({ right: "-250px" }, 300);

        // Closes tweet horizontally
        $tweet.stop().animate({ right: "-250px" }, 300);

        // Changes the button text to open
        $openClose.html('Open Menu ');

    } else { // run if button says "Open Menu"

        // Opens sidebar horizonally
        $sideBar.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);

        // Opens tweet horizontal
        $tweet.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);

        // Changes the button text to close
        $openClose.html('Close Menu');

    }
});
```

If you wondering why i'm binding the twitter slide up animation, it is because I need it slide the perfect height on the tweet, and the tweet height is dynamic, and can be various heights.

Any help to solve this would so awesome as my noodle is baking :/

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle: edited: http://jsfiddle.net/c8Mey/18/

I think it solves your problem, i've added an if statement to give a particular animation to the tweet section when the tab is opened

Comment: Thanks for having a go Nicosunshine, nearlly there!!! But if you scroll over red tweet area after opening and closing the sidebar once. The tweet and sidebar doesn't return. Otherwise apart from this, it works as it should.

Comment: Dude - you are a genius! Thank you so much!!! Nice move with the true and false, did not know you could do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

```
$tweetSlide.hover(function() {

        $tweetSlide.stop().animate({ top: "-" + tweetHeight + "px", right: "0" }, 300);
        $sideBar.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);

    }, function() {

        $tweetSlide.stop().animate({ top: "0", right: "-250px" }, 300);

        if ($showSidebar.html() == 'Open Menu') $sideBar.stop().animate({ right: "-250px" }, 300);

    });
```

You just need the `if ($showSidebar.html() == 'Open Menu')` condition.

However i just need to know if this is the effect you need. I think it still needs to be fixed a little.

**UPDATE**
I miss something

Change `$showSidebar.html('Open Menu ');`
For `$showSidebar.html('Open Menu');`

Remove the last white space or the condition won't work

Comment: See i've tried the if statements, but I can't logically work it out where I need to put them, as in I put in what you just said it breaks another. I will try again but I'm still novice at this.. Have you seen my jsFiddle, I have described the effect i'm after.

Comment: @user801773 Check out my update, i fixed the problem it causes. Perhaps describe your real scenario may help me out

Comment: Hi Chuck, i've described the real scenario here http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/3/ - thanks dude

Comment: @user801773 You know, that's the same fiddle. However try with the update i made, it's in the click event. Have to go, i'll check you answer later.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/c8Mey/16/ i've tried you idea, not really doing it :-(